# Импорт Entity Reference с помощью Feeds в Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, entity

Подскажите как импортировать значения для Entity Reference?

Вот есть такие поля в настройках Feeds импорта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я перепробовал все, но так и не смог добавить нужное значение. Оно каждый раз выставляется по дефолту.

Импортируемые значения имеют исключительно цифровой вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также я пробовал воспользоваться Tamper: Convert string into entity ID, однако он не видит вьюху с этим самым Entity Reference и соответственно не видит нужное поле.

Это настройка поля в типе материала:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это те поля которые видит Tamper:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]